# Catch all .htaccess - only if nothing is found before

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, catch-all

Is it possible to have exceptions to a catch all regex in a .htaccess file ?

Here is my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ see.php?url=$1 [L]
```

I would like to have some exceptions to the catch all regex and only use it in the last case, if nothing is found before.

I tried to play with RewriteCond, but I weren't able to make this work.

Edit: I would like exceptions to be rewrited as well, it this possible ?

Comment: What sort of conditions/exceptions would you like to add ?

Comment: I would like to specify differents URL with RewriteRule, and then, in the last case, if nothing is found, execute the catch-all regex and call see.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you place in the .htaccess file before the catch all rewrite will be executed first. So if you put an [L] flag on those rewrites then the processing stops there and the the catch all rewrite will not fire.

Make sense?

Comment: I think I managed to make it work: my rules were after `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, by moving them after `RewriteBase /`, it seems to works, thanks !