# .htaccess - hide php get variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

I have a webpage that I would like to rewrite the URL to. However, after about 1 hour of searching on Google and here, I couldn't find anything that made since to me, therefore, wouldn't work.

Current Website: www.example.com/page1/page2?var=1

I want that changed to www.example.com/page1/page2/1

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks,

ZG

Comment: When you search on google you will find a lot of examples ;) or search hier on Stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842027/catch-all-htaccess-only-if-nothing-is-found-before is one of the solutions

Answer (score 1):

Do you always have two components in the URI? If so, create an `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteModule On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$2?var=$3
```

Comment: `.+` or `[^/]+` would probably make more sense, though.