# .htaccess file working, but not rewriting url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The time has come to hide the get variables, but my .htaccess file wont allow the rewrite.I currently have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^timeline/(\d.*) timeline.php?user=$1
```

It is `timeline.php?user=chris` and it must read `timeline.php`

I have looked for close to 2 hours, copying and changing code, but nothing works.

I have also changed

```
<Directory ..>
...
AllowOverride None
...
</Directory>
```

to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Please help!

Comment: I don't think you can hide the get variables like that.  Best case you could do something like `timeline.php/user/chris` or similar, and your rewrite would stuff "chris" into the "user" $_GET variable.

Comment: Also, this is not a unique question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415685/htaccess-hide-php-get-variables

Comment: @cale_b I said I have been researching it for almost an hour, but none of that code helps

Comment: `\d` is digits, e.g. 0-9 only. `chris` will **NEVER** match, because those are letters, e.g a-z, not digits. Try `^timeline/(.*)` instead, or `^timeline/([a-z]*)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following htaccess and try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^timeline/([^/]*)$ /timeline.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This still doesn't rewrite the url

Comment: Are you sure your mod_rewrite is enabled? Its tested :(

Comment: Yes, I checked for that first

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^timeline/(.*)$ timeline.php?user=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to turn off `MultiViews` option by putting line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.